Why did Jacob say that seeing Esau's face was like seeing the face of God?
From Genesis 33:8-12 (NIV):

Esau asked, “What’s the meaning of all these flocks and herds I met?” "To find favor in your eyes, my lord,” he said. But Esau said, “I already have plenty, my brother. Keep what you have for yourself.” “No, please!” said Jacob. “If I have found favor in your eyes, accept this gift from me. For to see your face is like seeing the face of God, now that you have received me favorably. Please accept the present that was brought to you, for God has been gracious to me and I have all I need.” And because Jacob insisted, Esau accepted it.

Why was seeing Esau's face like seeing the face of God? What did Jacob mean by this?

Genesis 33:10 NIV

“No, please!” said Jacob. “If I have found favor in your eyes, accept this gift from me. For to see your face is like seeing the face of God, now that you have received me favorably.

Jacob's statement served as a poignant reflection on the eve before he going to meet with Esau. Genesis 32:6-8 describes Jacob was in deep distress upon learning that his brother was approaching him with 400 men. Faced with this formidable threat, he strategically divided his people into two groups, hoping that if one were attacked, the other might survive.
That night, Jacob encountered a mysterious man and engaged in a prolonged wrestling, unaware of the divine nature of his opponent. Only upon the dawn of realization did Jacob express his relief, acknowledging in Genesis 32:30, “It is because I saw God face to face, and yet my life was spared.”
The following day brought a profound sense of relief as Jacob found Esau's intentions is peaceful. In a moment Jacob found gratitude and recognition of divine intervention. Jacob likened seeing Esau's face to beholding the countenance of the Lord. This expression of gratitude stemmed from the assurance that his life had been spared and the acknowledgement of blessings bestowed by the divine hand.
It might be intriguing to note that Jacob offered an excuse to evade his brother Esau, as depicted in Genesis 33:12-17. I'll refrain from elaborating on this point here, leaving it to individual interpretation.

+1 ,,, Although personally I don't see Jacob as being unaware that he was wrestling with a supernatural being. I'd also had that I'm not sure Esau's intentions were peaceful at first. In one sense it was the other way around... In other words, Esau seems to have seen an enemy approaching, and it was he who was relieved when Jacob showed peaceful intent.

@DanFefferman - When did Jacob aware the man was an angel is subjective, but I firmly believe it did not occur at the initial encounter. Jocob chose to be alone is a sign of his trouble mental state. He drained his energy wrestling with the man seems to be an attempt to divert his mind from the impending reunion with his brother. When the angel could not overpower Jacob, he crippled Jacob by a touch, revived Jacob's awareness. Esau should recognised that Jacob only had his family. he arrived with 400 men seemed to carry a malicious intent, but divine intervention turn around the situation.

It is significant that Jacob reports saying this twice:

Gen 32:29, 30 - And Jacob requested, “Please tell me your name.” But he replied, “Why do you ask my name?” Then he blessed Jacob there. So Jacob named the place Peniel, [="face of God"] saying, “Indeed, I have seen God face to face, and yet my life was spared.” [See also Hos 12:4]
Gen 33:10 - But Jacob insisted, “No, please! If I have found favor in your sight, then receive this gift from my hand. For indeed, I have seen your face, and it is like seeing the face of God, since you have received me favorably.

There are two components of this remarkable statement:

Oriental hyperbole

According to Ellicott -

There is much of Oriental hyperbole in comparing the sight of Esau to
the beholding of the face of Deity, but it clearly conveyed the idea
that Esau was using his power as generously and lovingly as is the
wont of God; and God was so much nearer to the Hebrew in those simple
days than he is to men now that science has revealed to them the
immensity of His attributes, that there was no irreverence in the
comparison.


Common Figure of Speech

Note that hyperbolically comparing someone's wisdom or generosity to that God is found elsewhere; it is essentially saying that the person correctly imitates the grace as wisdom of God, perhaps by being divinely inspired:

1 Sam 29:9 - Achish replied, “I know that you [David] are as pleasing in my sight as an angel of God. But the commanders of the Philistines have said, ‘He must not go into battle with us.’
2 Sam 14:17 - And now your servant says, ‘May the word of my lord the king bring me rest, for my lord the king is able to discern good and evil, just like the angel of God. May the LORD your God be with you.’ ”

The Pulpit commentary is very helpful:

I have seen thy face, as though I had seen the face of God, - literally, as a vision of the face of Elohim, in which language Jacob
neither uses adulation towards his brother (Tostatius), nor calls him
a god in the sense in which heathen potentates are styled deities
(Vatablus, Arabic, Chaldee), nor simply uses a superlative expression
to indicate the majesty (Menochius) or benevolence (Ainsworth) of
Esau's countenance, contended with him at the Jabbok (Bush); but
either that

he had received from Esau the same friendly welcome that one coming into God's presence would receive from him (Rosenmüller, Keil, Murphy,
'Speaker's Commentary'),
or that he had come into Esau's presence with the same feelings of penitence as if he had been coming before God (Kalisch),
or that, as he had already seen the face of God and his life was preserved, so now he had seen the face of Esau, and the anticipated
destruction had not been inflicted on him



+1 You've hit the nail on the head by drawing our attention to the fact that Jacob first 'sees the face' of God in his wrestling with the angel and then with his external foe  Esau, with whom he wrestled in the womb. I may give my own answer later to expand on this theme.

There are several dimensions to this profound providential moment.

On the human level, this was merely a figure or speech designed to placate or flatter Esau. The context is that Esau had  just demurred when Jacob offered gifts to him. Jacob insisted, using this phrase as leverage, because it was important to Jacob that he not be in a position of owning Esau anything upon the former's return to Canaan. (Compare Abraham's insistence to pay Ephron the Hittite for the Cave of Machpelah in Gen. 23.)

Internally or "vertically," Jacob first saw the "face of God" in winning his wrestling match with the angel after 21 years of oppression under Laban. Externally he then saw the "face of God" in Esau, with whom he had wrestled in the womb (Genesis 25:22) and engaged a lifelong struggle for supremacy. In both cases, seeing the face of God in his adversary represented the victorious culmination of a long and difficult struggle.

Seeing the face of God in Esau anticipated the teaching of Jesus to "love your enemy and pray for those who persecute you." Esau had planned to kill Jacob after losing the birthright to him; and when Jacob returned, Esau met him with 400 armed men. By his long course of 21 years of difficulty under Laban and then winning the internal struggle with the angel, Jacob established a foundation for success with Esau, who had reason to resent him. But he first had to win over Esau's heart, which he did by sending substantial gifts to him and bowing down to him seven times. In so doing, Jacob established a model course for each of us. He struggled with Laban and eventually received his blessing. He struggled with God's angel and won his blessing as well. Finally, he embraced his former enemy Esau and could see the face of God in him as well. In this moment, though the face of the person who formerly sought to kill him, God welcomed Jacob home.


Conclusion: To see the face of God in his brother Esau was the culmination of Jacob's course of 21 years in exile, representing both his own ability to win the heart of his former enemy and God's blessing on the conclusion of Jacob's course of restoration.

I lean towards the grace and mercy that Esau showed.  Here is a comment on the possible meanings.

like seeing the face of God This rhetorical extravagance yields, perhaps intentionally, several possible meanings: encountering you, Esau, is like a pilgrimage to a shrine, which one does not make empty-handed; I have been admitted to your august presence; you have been graciously indulgent of me; my encounter with you is like that with a divine being. This last would be an artfully astute reference to 32:31.
--
Sarna, N. M. (1989). Genesis (p. 230). Jewish Publication Society.

